# Could someone explain to me what is returned in this if statement

Tags: c#

```
public void OnPressHigher()
    {
       if (min >= max || guess == max) return;
        min = guess + 1;
        NextGuess();
    }
```

I can't figure out what is returned in this if statement.

Comment: Welcome. Have you checked the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/void)?

Comment: `return` with no value after it means to return out of the method, not to return a value.

Comment: Sloppy indentation like that is a bug waiting to happen

Comment: nothing. explicitly _nothing_ is returned, and nothing ever _can_ be returned from a method that is `void`. it just stops execution of the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing returned because your functions return type is `void`. In the context in your code it means that if the condition `min >= max || guess == max` isn't met, the function shouldn't continue to execute and should return to it's caller.

Answer (score 2):

The method is declared as returning void

```
public void OnPressHigher()
```

Which means it will **never** return anything.
Therefore, a return instruction will simply exit the method at that point and not execute any further instructions within the method.